# SwiftUI, Why ONLY ONE 'navigationBarItems' is shown?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to show two `navigationBarItems` in my app, so I added two `navigationBarItems` but only one is shown.

Here is my code

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                Text("Something")
            }.navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Text1"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:Text("Text2"))
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how looks like in Xcode
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update the code that sets the navigationBarItems to this:

```swift
.navigationBarItems(leading: Text("Text1"), trailing: Text("Text2"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set multiple navigation items as a HStack:

```swift
.navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack {
    Button("Action 1") { print("Action 1") }
    Button("Action 2") { print("Action 2") }
})
```